# Nodejs express prisma-session-store strange error

Tags: express, prisma, express-session

The package `prisma-session-store` refuses to work
this is my settings

```
  session({
    store: new PrismaSessionStore(new PrismaClient(), {
      checkPeriod: 2 * 60 * 1000, //ms
      dbRecordIdIsSessionId: true,
      dbRecordIdFunction: undefined
    }),
    name: 'sid',
    secret: process.env.KEY,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : true,
      maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // ms
    }
  })
);
```

and I have this weird error
Knowing prisma works perfect outside the package

````
set(): Error:
Invalid `this.prisma[this.sessionModelName].update()` invocation in
/Users/hossam/wk/pim/node_modules/@quixo3/prisma-session-store/dist/lib/prisma-session-store.js:493:81

  490 case 3:
  491     _a.trys.push([3, 8, , 9]);
  492     if (!(existingSession !== null)) return [3 /*break*/, 5];
→ 493     return [4 /*yield*/, this.prisma[this.sessionModelName].update(
  The provided value for the column is too long for the column's type. Column: data
Error:
Invalid `this.prisma[this.sessionModelName].update()` invocation in
/Users/hossam/wk/pim/node_modules/@quixo3/prisma-session-store/dist/lib/prisma-session-store.js:493:81

  490 case 3:
  491     _a.trys.push([3, 8, , 9]);
  492     if (!(existingSession !== null)) return [3 /*break*/, 5];
→ 493     return [4 /*yield*/, this.prisma[this.sessionModelName].update(
  The provided value for the column is too long for the column's type. Column: data
    at RequestHandler.request (/Users/hossam/wk/pim/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:49022:15)
    at async PrismaClient._request (/Users/hossam/wk/pim/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:49919:18)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says the column value for `data` is too long. This is a field on the `Session` model, in your `schema.prisam` that [prisma session store](https://github.com/kleydon/prisma-session-store#model) says to create. I think you'll have to make that column larger. I don't know which database your using but here are the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#string) for a string.

If you set it up like this `data String` in your `schema.prisma` then check the docs for the default value of string based on your database.

You can add `data String @db.VarChar(<insert length here>)` to explicitly set the character length.